# Amazon API answers MissingClientTokenId

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Access key and secret key and associate_tag is correct then have trouble 
when I send request then I get this response:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (2) { ["Error"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (2) { ["Code"]=> string(20) "MissingClientTokenId" ["Message"]=> string(57) "Request must contain AWSAccessKeyId or X.509 certificate." } ["RequestId"]=> string(36) "3dda37ed-5b92-4b83-a95e-c19db6b4288c" }
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
$keywords='Learning PHP, MySQL'; 
$associate_tag = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$aws_secret_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$aws_access_key_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$item_page=10;
 $base_url = 'http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId;=' . '$aws_access_key_id' . '&';
//Set parameters for API search, see AWS documentation for a detailed list of parameters
$url_params = array(
            'Operation'=>'ItemSearch',
            'ItemPage'=>$item_page,
            'AssociateTag'=>$associate_tag,
            'Version'=>'2013-08-01',
            'ResponseGroup'=>'Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview',
             'SearchIndex'=>'Books',
             'Keywords'=>rawurlencode($keywords)
         );

        //Sort the URL parameters
        $url_parts = array();
        foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
            $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
        sort($url_parts);

        //Build and encode the request URL
        $url = $base_url . implode('&',$url_parts);
        $host = parse_url($base_url . implode('&',$url_parts),PHP_URL_HOST);
        $timestamp = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z');
        $url = $url. '&Timestamp;=' . $timestamp;
        $paramstart = strpos($url,'?');
        $workurl = substr($url,$paramstart+1);
        $workurl = str_replace(",",",",$workurl);
        $workurl = str_replace(":",":",$workurl);
        $params = explode("&",$workurl);
        sort($params);
        $signstr = "GET\n" . $host . "\n/onca/xml\n" . implode("&",$params);
        $signstr = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $signstr, $aws_secret_access_key, true));
        $signstr = urlencode($signstr);
        $signedurl = $url . "&Signature;=" . $signstr;
        $request = $signedurl;    

        //Send request to AWS
        $session = curl_init($request);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session); 
        $parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        var_dump($parsed_xml);exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, ***base_url*** variable is not getting set. And there are so many unneccessary ";" in the code, tried to correct it like:-

```
$keywords='Learning PHP, MySQL'; 
$associate_tag = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$aws_secret_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$aws_access_key_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$item_page=10;

$base_url = 'http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId='. $aws_access_key_id .'&';

#echo $base_url;


//Set parameters for API search, see AWS documentation for a detailed list of parameters
 $url_params = array(
        'Operation'=>'ItemSearch',
        'ItemPage'=>$item_page,
        'AssociateTag'=>$associate_tag,
        'Version'=>'2013-08-01',
        'ResponseGroup'=>'Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview',
         'SearchIndex'=>'Books',
         'Keywords'=>rawurlencode($keywords)
     );

    //Sort the URL parameters
    $url_parts = array();
    foreach(array_keys($url_params) as $key)
        $url_parts[] = $key."=".$url_params[$key];
    sort($url_parts);

    //Build and encode the request URL
    $url = $base_url . implode('&',$url_parts);
    $host = parse_url($base_url . implode('&',$url_parts),PHP_URL_HOST);
    $timestamp = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z');
    $url = $url. '&Timestamp=' . $timestamp;
    $paramstart = strpos($url,'?');
    $workurl = substr($url,$paramstart+1);
    $workurl = str_replace(",",",",$workurl);
    $workurl = str_replace(":",":",$workurl);
    $params = explode("&",$workurl);
    sort($params);
    $signstr = "GET\n" . $host . "\n/onca/xml\n" . implode("&",$params);
    $signstr = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $signstr,$aws_secret_access_key, true));
    $signstr = urlencode($signstr);
    $signedurl = $url . "&Signature=" . $signstr;
    $request = $signedurl;
    echo $request;

    //Send request to AWS
    $session = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session); 
    $parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    var_dump($parsed_xml);exit;
```

Comment: now get this error The request must contain the parameter Signature

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Error] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Code] => MissingParameter [Message] => The request must contain the parameter Signature. ) [RequestId] => a497f313-a621-4098-97e4-965665d0f316 )

Comment: Check for the spaces or extra ";" in the "$request" variable. Your request URL is not properly sent.

Comment: this is url request $base_url = 'http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=' . '$aws_access_key_id' . '&';

Comment: i copy paste url you provide me in me function

Comment: have no space $request veriable

Comment: My Bad! I have just updated that $base_url again. Please use that.

Comment: i can not understand please explain what i do?

Comment: Can you please be specific as what you did and what you are not able to understand?

Comment: this error MissingParameter  how to solve ? i have lot of try but helpless whay it is

Comment: Looks like your code requires lot of edits. So many ";" in between creating wrong request URL. Updating my answer, please check that.

Comment: response is SignatureDoesNotMatch

Comment: Now the earlier error is gone and came down to "SignatureDoesNotMatc‌​h". Now, Go though AWS API : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/
If it doesnt get resolved, please open separate question.